# How to update in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having some problem to implement the update in my Laravel app.
In my blade file I have a modal where I show the fields in a . Every row as a button that opens another modal where every fields should be updated. So this is the blade file:

```
<form action="{{ action('AnamController@update', $par->id_par) }}" method="put" class="form-horizontal">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input name="input_name" value="Par" hidden />

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$par->name}}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--other things-->
</form>
```

But this return to me an error. "Property [id_par] does not exist on this collection instance" and if I insert a foreach statement when I press the button edit to open the modal I always see the first field present in the db. So what I have to do?

Thanks

**EDIT**
This is the route:

```
Route::post('/anam/{id}, AnamController@update')->name('anam');
```

**EDIT 2**
I try to implement the update function to see if the update works. But I have error MethodNotAllowedHttpException

This is what I wrote:

```
   public function update(Request $request, $id){

    $par = Par::find($id);
    $par->name = $request->input('name');
    $par->save();

    return redirect('/anam');
}
```

Comment: try changing the `$par->id_par` to a static `id` that exists in your database then tell me if your update works

Comment: change form method `put` to `post`

Answer (score 1):

First of for an update you need to change the `form` element method should be `post` and then add a blade directive `@method('put')` for newer laravel versions or `{{ method_field('PUT') }}` for older within the form.

Please share some more code not only the view so we can see what causes the error that you get.

Comment: Yes I have already tried to write post to the method attribute in the <form> but it doesn't solve my problem. So I'll try to change it but without any success.

Comment: your route should be `put` not `post`. But I am interested in seeing how are you passing this `$par` variable and what does it contain. Because that's where the error comes from.

Comment: I'll pass it in the index function of my controller in this way $par = Par::where('id_pazi', Auth::id())->get(); then I'll put the variable in the view function.

Comment: Change `$par = Par::where('id_pazi', Auth::id())->get(); ` to `$par = Par::where('id_pazi', Auth::id())->first();`

Comment: If I change get() with first() I have an error: "Trying to get property 'id_par' of non-object"

Comment: It should work. Can you post the table schema as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Your route has to be this :

`Route::put('/anam/{id}, AnamController@update')->name('anam');`

not

`Route::post('/anam/{id}, AnamController@update')->name('anam');`

AND in your form use this

```
<form action="{{ action('AnamController@update', $par->id_par) }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
{{csrf_field()}}
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

EDIT :

You might have an issue with the name of your primary key :

is your primary key of the `Par` Model is id_par ?

check in your console that the request is on the right id (ex : /aname/10)

then try to add a `dd($id);` in your controller to see if the id you have is the right one.

PS: You should try a ressource controller with automatic Model Binding

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#implicit-binding

Comment: The update function works but there is still the problem that in the modal I always see the first row of my table in db.